# GET Not working because of Hash user.php?#access_token=123

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, get, facebook-oauth, request-uri

looked high and low for an answer to this and can not find anything. My redirect uri from the Facebook OAuth is returning with a # before the parameters, apparently this is meant to happen, but is now stopping a $_GET request for the access token. What is the best way to get hold of the token?

URL Example:
http://website.co.uk/user.php?#access_token=123

Facebooks Explanation:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318390728250352?fb_comment_id=fbc_10151751027806988_358309612_10151883481651988

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use javascript document.URL to get the absolute url on page load, the remove # from that string and use it with window.location to redirect to url without # in it.
is that what you want?

Comment: I wanted to achieve it without a redirect but I guess this seems the most simple of solutions. Thanks